# ffmpeg forcing the usage of nvenc instead of libx264 c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

The code below works, but it loads the nvenc encoder instead of the libx264 encoder, which I need for 0 latency streaming.

```
this->pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (this->pCodec == NULL)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't initialize the encoder. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:9\n");

this->pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(this->pCodec);

//Alloc output context
if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatCtx, NULL, "rtsp", url) < 0)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't alloc stream output. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:17\n");
```

How can I force the usage of x264 ?

Comment: Use `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264")` instead of `avcodec_find_encoder`

Comment: @AndreyTurkin It returns NULL unfortunatly

Comment: Most likely your ffmpeg libraries are built without libx264 support. In fact, avcodec_find_encoder would've selected libx264 codec too if it was available.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin You are right, I am trying to build ffmpeg with x264 support, but it does not find the library